# Picture credits -> must the page of inclusion be named?

Tags: intellectual-property, attribution

we're currently developing a website. For this we use pictures for which we need to place an attribution on the legal notice page.

Now we're wondering if it's enough to place the following information there:

- file name
- path
- image content (i.e. the visual image itself)
- the copyright (maybe including link)

Is this enough or do we need to include also the urls of the sub pages where we place the image?

Thanks in advance!

Bye The_Unknown

Answer (score 1):

Just giving a credit does not absolve you of the copyright regulations. The person who owns the copyright on the images would need to allow you to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first: I assume that I have all the permissions to use the image by the author. My questions only targets the attribution my website’s legal section. What exactly do you mean by „just giving a credit“? Could you please refer to the original question? Do I need to mention the web address (URL), *where on my website exactly* the image is embedded or is it enough to mention the copyright string next to the image itself and the author’s name and link in the legal section of my website?

Comment: What do you mean? If you have permission you can do whatever you want. It's an either you have permission or you don't type thing, not a you have to list x.

Comment: ??? Did you ever heard of image attribution? See here for example https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/best_practices_for_attribution

Comment: @The_Unknown that refers only to images licensed under that specific license. Is the image given that specific license?

Comment: @The_Unknown if the image is under that license you need to put the four things listed there : Title, Author, Source, and License. If you do that you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the source of your "permission". If for example the permission is via a public license which say "must attribute" without being more specific, then the question is whether your efforts to comply with that requirement are "reasonable". Observation of typical attribution statements will tell you what is reasonable (because it is assumed that most people are reasonable). If it is customary that attribution statements include information such as "URL1 of ours comes from SOURCE1; URL2 of ours comes from SOURCE2...", then that would inform you of one reasonable outcome. Alternatively, if it is customary that items simply be acknowledged somewhere, e.g. "We thank SOURCE1, SOURCE2... for permission to reproduce their stuff", then it is reasonable to limit the attribution to that. Mainly: whatever the license says; secondarily, whatever is "reasonable" in case a specific detail is not stated in the license.